# How do I set 301 redirects to strip off .html file extensions?

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on migrating a MovableType blog to Wordpress.

All of the old post urls end in .html.

Example:

```
http://ec2-174-129-85-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com/archives/2013/12/all_quiet_on_th.html
```

However, when I updated the post names in wordpress to include the .html extensions, I kept getting 404 errors.

So what I want to do now is redirect all of the requests for pages that end in .html to the same pages but without the .html.

For example:

```
.../archives/2013/12/all_quiet_on_th.html
```

Would 301 redirect to:

```
.../archives/2013/12/all_quiet_on_th
```

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# Ensure the rewriet module is loaded
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Set the root directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can you please advise what changes I can make to this file for this to work?

I tried 5 or 6 different versions on the internet already, but it is not working and I am not sure why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# Ensure the rewriet module is loaded
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Set the root directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```